# Elasticsearch merge multiple indexes based on common field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I'm using ELK to generate views out of the data from two different DB. One is mysql other one is PostgreSQL. There is no way of writing join query between those two DB instance. But I have a common field call "nic". Following are the documents from each index.

**MySQL**

index: user_detail

```
"_id": "871123365V",
"_source": {
    "type": "db-poc-user",
    "fname": "Iraj",
    "@version": "1",
    "field_lname": "Sanjeewa",
    "nic": "871456365V",
    "@timestamp": "2020-07-22T04:12:00.376Z",
    "id": 2,
    "lname": "Santhosh"
  }
```

**PostgreSQL**

Index: track_details

```
"_id": "871456365V",
"_source": {
   "@version": "1",
   "nic": "871456365V",
   "@timestamp": "2020-07-22T04:12:00.213Z",
   "track": "ELK",
   "type": "db-poc-ceg"
},
```

I want to merge both index in to single index using common field "nic". And create new index. So I can create visualization on Kibana. How can this be achieved?

> Please note that each document in new index should have
> "nic,fname,lname,track" as fields. Not the aggregation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would leverage the [enrich processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html) to achieve this.

First, you need to create an enrich policy (use the smallest index, let's say it's `user_detail`):

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/user-policy
{
  "match": {
    "indices": "user_detail",
    "match_field": "nic",
    "enrich_fields": ["fname", "lname"]
  }
}
```

Then you can execute that policy in order to create an enrichment index

```
POST /_enrich/policy/user-policy/_execute
```

The next step requires you to create an ingest pipeline that uses the above enrich policy/index:

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/user_lookup
{
  "description" : "Enriching user details with tracks",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "enrich" : {
        "policy_name": "user-policy",
        "field" : "nic",
        "target_field": "tmp",
        "max_matches": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "if": "ctx.tmp != null",
        "source": "ctx.putAll(ctx.tmp); ctx.remove('tmp');"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": ["@version", "@timestamp", "type"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, you're now ready to create your target index with the joined data. Simply leverage the `_reindex` API combined with the ingest pipeline we've just created:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "track_details"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "user_tracks",
    "pipeline": "user_lookup"
  }
}
```

After running this, the `user_tracks` index will contain exactly what you need, for instance:

```
  {
    "_index" : "user_tracks",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "0uA8dXMBU9tMsBeoajlw",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "fname" : "Iraj",
      "nic" : "871456365V",
      "lname" : "Santhosh",
      "track" : "ELK"
    }
  }
```

If your source indexes ever change (new users, changed names, etc), you'll need to re-run the above steps, but before doing it, you need to delete the ingest pipeline and the ingest policy (in that order):

```
DELETE /_ingest/pipeline/user_lookup
DELETE /_enrich/policy/user-policy
```

After that you can freely re-run the above steps.

PS: Just note that I cheated a bit since the record in `user_detail` doesn't have the same `nic` in your example, but I guess it was a copy/paste issue.

Comment: This is working perfect. But if we want to repeatedly regenerate growing index then what is the step?

Comment: Thanks. Working great. First step to be skipped if we regenerate again.

Comment: The first step needs to be done as well if the `user_detail` indexes changes (new users, name updates, etc)

Comment: It was throwing "resource_already_exists_exception" error while running second time. Any way i insert new data to both index while testing. it worked.

Comment: Yes, you need to DELETE the policy and recreate it on each run. I've updated my answer with the detailed steps

Comment: @Vel In this example, Kibana failed to load date filter. Any idea why it happen? I even test it by adding and removing these fields ("field": ["@version", "@timestamp", "type"]). but same issue.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question and expose the issue you're having now