# Can I query two different indexes with different structures and merge results in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out if a particular type of query is possible with Elasticsearch and, if so, how to actually write that query.

I have two indexes, `groups` and `challenges`. The shape of the data for these two indexes are different, but they both have a field named `id`.

I want to search across different fields for the two indexes. For example, for `groups` I want to search across `code`, `name`, `description`. For `challenges`, it's the same fields, but also a few others, some in nested data.

I was able to get a simple query running that seemed to return the combination of results from both indexes using a URI query without specifying an index. EG: `/search?q=some%20search`. Cool.

However, I need to filter the results so that they only include groups and challenges that the current user is permitted to see. In my application I can easily get a list of these, `permitted_group_ids` and `permitted_challenge_ids`. I had planned on switching to a json body query and adding a filter, but I've not been able to figure out the syntax, especially regarding the filter.

So, a couple questions:

1. What is the json query syntax to do a free-form query similar to `/search?q=some%20search`? The documentation seems to say that I should somehow use `bool`, but it seems like I need to manually specify the fields to search across (which are different between the two indexes) and that they all must match the search string.
2. How can I filter the results to exclude based on `id` in different indexes?

In pseudocode, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

> Dear Elasticsearch,
>
> Please find all records in the `groups` and `challenges` indexes that match the string "zamboni". Once you've identified those, please restrict the groups to only those whose `id` value is in [1, 2, 3] and the challenges to those whose `id` value is in [3, 4, 5]. Thanks!
>
> Sincerely, Your Friendly Neighborhood Developer.

Any sort of help would be appreciated, even pointing me to specific bits of the Elasticsearch docs to read. Thank you!

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63028335/4604579

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
GET groups,challenges/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "_source": false, // or ["whatever", "data", "you", "need"]
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {"bool": {"must": [
          {"term": {"_index": "groups"}},
          {"term": {"code": "zamboni"}},
          {"term": {"name": "zamboni"}},
          {"term": {"description": "zamboni"}},
          {"terms": {"id": [1, 2, 3]}}
        ]}},
        {"bool": {"must": [
          {"term": {"_index": "challenges"}},
          {"term": {"code": "zamboni"}},
          {"term": {"name": "zamboni"}},
          {"term": {"description": "zamboni"}},
          {"terms": {"id": [3, 4, 5]}}
        ]}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks pretty promising. I've gotten closer to what I need since posting this question and it's not too far off of this. I'm using multi_match instead of separate terms. I'm also changing the index to include the ids for users who have access to a given group. (I realized anyone can see a challenge.) Now I just need to filter groups based on the user's id.