# Perform JOIN operation in an efficient way in real time on two data sources produced by Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, inner-join

We have two very large flat Elasticsearch indices: `variant` and `genotype`. Each item of the latter index - `genotype` - has `variantId` to connect to a document in the `variant` index. We need to do a regular `JOIN` operation - for each `variant` document in a list get all of the `genotype` ones as a list - but `Elasticsearch` is not able to perform it in any efficient way. So, we are wondering if such a `JOIN` can be performed outside `ES` by some separately run tool/engine (Kafka, Spark, we are not sure)? We could issue two `ES` queries and feed them into the engine which would output joined result. What would be the best tool for the goal? Could anyone give some links to resources or to how this particular problem could be addressed?

Previously we tried to just store `genotype` as a nested field in the `variant` documents but because there are too many of both of them and there is a hard limit on the number of nested fields we needed to abandon that idea.

Comment: If one of the indexes doesn't change too often, there is also another possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63028335/4604579 (hint: use enrich processor)

Comment: The problem is that I need the JOIN operation to return the results right away, asap, and usually creation of a new index, _reindex operation are pretty slow, right? The user is waiting for results and shown a loading indicator, so things should be done very fast.

Comment: The enrich processor is used as indexing time in such a way that two data sources (i.e. indexes) can be merged together (based on variantId) and then the joined data is available at search time.

Comment: Oh, ok, got it. Need to think, thank you!